# How can I force HttpClient to send the Connection header?

Tags: .net, vb.net, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

HttpClient doesn't send the Connection (keep-alive) header by default. How can I force it to do so?  I'm pretty sure this needs to be done via reflection but unsure how.

Similar to the following question but I want to know how to force it for HttpClient not HttpWebRequest.

[C# - Connection: keep-alive Header is Not Being Sent During HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458556/c-sharp-connection-keep-alive-header-is-not-being-sent-during-httpwebrequest)

I need to use HTTP 1.1, so switching to 1.0 isn't an option.

EDIT 1: Adding code sample as requested;

```
  Public Overridable Async Function WebRequestAsync(Url As String, Optional RequestMethod As RequestMethod = RequestMethod.GET, Optional Content As Object = Nothing, _
                                              Optional ContentType As ContentType = ContentType.Default, Optional Accept As String = DefaultAcceptString, _
                                              Optional AdditionalHeaders As NameValueCollection = Nothing, Optional Referer As String = Nothing, _
                                              Optional NoCache As Boolean = False, Optional CustomCookieHandler As Boolean = False, _
                                              Optional OutputBufferKey As String = Nothing, Optional CancellationToken As CancellationToken? = Nothing, _
                                              Optional Attempts As Integer = 2, Optional CanBeCancelled As Boolean = True) _
                                   As Tasks.Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)

    If OutputBufferKey Is Nothing Then OutputBufferKey = Me.OutputBufferKey
    If CancellationToken Is Nothing Then CancellationToken = Me.CancellationToken
    If TypeOf Content Is PostData Then Content = Content.ToString

    If Attempts < 1 Then Attempts = 1

    Dim Method As HttpMethod = Nothing
    Select Case RequestMethod
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.DELETE : Method = HttpMethod.Delete
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.GET : Method = HttpMethod.Get
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.OPTIONS : Method = HttpMethod.Options
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.POST : Method = HttpMethod.Post
      Case Variables.RequestMethod.PUT : Method = HttpMethod.Put
    End Select

    'prepare message
    Dim Message As New HttpRequestMessage(Method, Url)
    Message.Headers.ExpectContinue = False
    If Accept IsNot Nothing Then Message.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", Accept)
    If Referer IsNot Nothing Then Message.Headers.Add("Referer", Referer)
    If NoCache Then
      Message.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache")
      Message.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    End If
    If AdditionalHeaders IsNot Nothing Then
      For Each Key In AdditionalHeaders.AllKeys
        Message.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(Key, AdditionalHeaders(Key))
      Next
    End If

    'set content
    If RequestMethod = Variables.RequestMethod.POST Then
      Dim ContentTypeString As String = GetEnumDescription(ContentType)

      Dim ContentBytes As Byte() = New Byte() {}

      If Content IsNot Nothing Then
        If TypeOf Content Is String Then
          ContentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CType(Content, String))
        ElseIf TypeOf Content Is Byte() Then
          ContentBytes = CType(Content, Byte())
        ElseIf TypeOf Content Is MultiPartPostData Then
          Dim MultiPartPostData As MultiPartPostData = CType(Content, MultiPartPostData)
          ContentBytes = MultiPartPostData.Bytes
          ContentTypeString += "; boundary=" & MultiPartPostData.Boundary
        End If
      End If

      Dim ByteArrayContent As New ByteArrayContent(ContentBytes)
      ByteArrayContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", ContentTypeString)
      Message.Content = ByteArrayContent
    End If

    Output(OutputBufferKey, RequestMethod.ToString & " " & Url, OutputType.Debug)

    'Set cancellation token

    Dim TimeoutToken As New CancellationTokenSource
    If CancellationToken IsNot Nothing AndAlso CancellationToken.HasValue AndAlso CanBeCancelled Then TimeoutToken = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(CancellationToken.Value)
    TimeoutToken.CancelAfter(CInt(DefaultTimeout * 1.2))

    'get response
    Dim Response As HttpResponseMessage = Nothing
    For Attempt = 1 To Attempts
      Try
        Response = Await Client.SendAsync(Message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, TimeoutToken.Token).ConfigureAwait(False)
      Catch ex As Exception When TypeOf ex Is HttpRequestException OrElse TypeOf ex Is Tasks.TaskCanceledException
        If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
          If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, Method.ToString & " " & Url & " " & ex.InnerException.Message, OutputType.Error)
          If ex.InnerException.Message = "Timed out" Then Continue For
        Else
          If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, Method.ToString & " " & Url & " " & ex.Message, OutputType.Error)
        End If
      Catch ex As Exception
        If DebugMode Then Output(OutputBufferKey, Method.ToString & " " & Url & " " & ex.Message, OutputType.Error)
      End Try

      Exit For
    Next

    If Response IsNot Nothing Then
      Output(OutputBufferKey, Method.ToString & " " & Url & " " & Response.StatusCode & " " & Response.StatusCode.ToString, OutputType.Debug)
      If CustomCookieHandler AndAlso Cookies IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim Values As IEnumerable(Of String) = Nothing
        If Response.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", Values) Then ManuallyExtractCookies(Values, New Uri(Url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))
      End If
    End If

    Return Response
  End Function
```

Comment: Can you post your code which you use to send your data? You might need a `HttpRequestMessage` in which you can set any header you want.

Comment: @Stefan Added code, but as far as I know, that header cannot be set manually (it is a restricted header).  The way to set it is the `KeepAlive` property of `HttpClient`.  The problem is that when set to true the header isn't sent, only when set as false.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point, although I thought `keep alive` could be set with `Message.Headers.Add("` etc. If that doesn't help, reflection might help to set some internal values but I wouldn't know which ones to set.

Comment: @iguanaman It isn't sent because keep-alive behaviour is the default behaviour for Http/1.1  You shouldn't need to send a keep-alive header for the server to keep the connection open.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thanks, I am aware of this but the server isn't respecting it unless the header is sent for some reason.  Not my server, so my only option is to force the header to be sent.

Comment: @iguanaman Unfortunately the default behaviour of HttpClient is to use HttpWebRequest under the covers.  The HttpClientHandler class encapsulates this behaviour.  You would need to use a replacement for that class.  At the moment there are only a few available replacements and chances are they might force the same behaviour.